# Calculate Memory Cost and CPU cost for training and testing of machine learning/deep learning Model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I have a question regarding computing resource cost for training and testing of machine learning or deep learning algorithms. Any suggestion how can I calculate or extract resource cost like memory overhead and cpu overhead for t instance in time?
If there is any formula that I can use or extract it  from the computer I am using to train and test my algorithm

Any suggestion will be really helpful

Comment: Not really a formula, but Pytorch has a module named [torchsummary](https://pypi.org/project/torch-summary/) that does this kind of calculation and display the result, I don't know exactly how it is done tho, but can help you check if your results are correct. The librayr is based on [this article](http://jck.bio/pytorch_estimating_model_size/) apprently, which can probably help answering your question

Answer (score 1):

The Floating Point Operations (FLOP) or Events Per Cycle (EPC) are  representative measures of CPU activity.

Libraries like python-papi can extract many CPU events (low level or high level):
http://www.bnikolic.co.uk/blog/python/flops/2019/09/27/python-counting-events.html

https://flozz.github.io/pypapi/papi_high.html